# How to work with nested JSON "and/or" condition or any other condition

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

In PostgreSQL 14, I am trying using JSONB_PATH_QUERY in nested JSON, but it not working.

Here  I am searching for and condition in nested JSON, it should not match but it is given result. How can I write the SQL where nested JSON and condition working.

I am trying using JSONB_PATH_QUERY, but it not working.

```
select jsonb_path_query('[{"parent":"test","child":[{"key":"1000","name":"A"},{"key":"1001","name":"B"}]}]',
    '$[*] ? (@.parent == "test" && @.child.key == "1000" && @.child.name == "B")')
```

Output :

```
{
  "child": [{"key": "1000", "name": "A"}, {"key": "1001", "name": "B"}], 
  "parent": "test"
}
```

Expected result:

- should not match,
- It should only match when is search for `@.child.key == "1000" && @.child.name == "A" && @.parent == "test" or @.child.key == "1001" && @.child.name == "B" && @.parent == "test"`

Here  I am searching for `@.child.key == "1000" && @.child.name == "B" && @.parent == "test"`, it should not match but it is given result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to iterate over the `child` keys so that name and key are taken from the same array element:

```
jsonb_path_query(..., '$[*].child ? (@.key == "1000" && @.name == "B")') as q
```

If you need a condition on the `parent` key, you can combine multiple conditions:

```
jsonb_path_query(..., '$[*] ? (@.parent == "test").child[*] ? (@.key == "1000" && @.name == "B")') as q
```